# Does a bulk automatically execute when it is full on elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using the elasticsearch java API.

I have a bulk request and I am adding several update request in this bulk. I don't have the number of update that I am doing, because it depends on previous actions.

```
bulkRequest.add(esClientManager.getEsClient().prepareUpdate(...).setDoc(...).setDocAsUpsert(true));
```

I could be doing this add millions of time.

My question is simple: will the bulk executes itself when it will be full or I have to check by myself and execute it while needed (using numberOfActions to retrieve the number of request in bulk ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it yourself.  As to when, it depends on your data. For everything I've done, I try to do about 1000 records (which in my case works out to about a 500K bulk request).  This seems to be a good memory/time trade-off.

What I typically do is something like this

```
BulkRequestBuilder br = null;
/// some looping construct
while (rs.next()) {
   if (br != null && br.numberOfActions() >= batchSize) {
     processResponse(br.execute().get());
     br = null;
   }
   if (br == null) {
     br = client.prepareBulk();
   }
   // do whatever to create IndexRequest
   br.add(ir);
}
if (br != null) {
  processResponse(br.execute().get());
}
```

Comment: So here your batchSize would be 1000 ? I need to bulk like 4M data, I will try the solution

Comment: Yes.  In my case is a config file value in case it needs tweaked.